# Path for PHP 7 - using the "|" character

Tags: php, xpath

```
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($source);
    $xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

    //$rowxpath = $post->xpath;
    $rowxpath = '//*[@class="s-lg-az-result s-lg-az-result-new"]'; 
    $elementsn =  $xpath->query($rowxpath);
```

In the above, $elementsn->length is not 0. But when

```
$rowxpath = '//*[@class="s-lg-az-result"] ｜ //*[@class="s-lg-az-result s-lg-az-result-new"]';
```

it's always 0. The path doesn't seem to work when the | character is used.

How come, and how can I solve this?

NOTE: for what I used for $source, please see https://can-la.com/samplesforstackexc/test3.html.

Also note: if you are going to file_get_contents('https://can-la.com/samplesforstackexc/test3.html'); this would produce some errors related to SSL:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed in /Users/user/HoldingForDO/libTOdatabases/index.php on line 48

Warning: file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto in /Users/user/HoldingForDO/libTOdatabases/index.php on line 48

Warning: file_get_contents(https://can-la.com/samplesforstackexc/test3.html): failed to open stream: operation failed in /Users/user/HoldingForDO/libTOdatabases/index.php on line 48
```

However, this is not the issue, as I am only uploading this file to can-la.com to serve as a sample for this question. Even if u download the file and file_get_contents('test3.html') directly, the problem still arises.

Comment: [Can't reproduce your issue.](https://3v4l.org/gTtiK)

Comment: @Jeto try using this html: https://can-la.com/samplesforstackexc/test3.html. the problem arose when using this for $source.

Comment: Also note: if you are going to file_get_contents(('https://can-la.com/samplesforstackexc/test3.html'); this would produce some errors related to SSL (see my updated version of this post for the errors). However, this is not the issue, as I am only uploading this file to can-la.com to serve as a sample for this question. Even if u download the file and file_get_contents('test3.html') directly, the problem still arises.

Comment: Does `$rowxpath = '//*[@class="s-lg-az-result" or @class="s-lg-az-result s-lg-az-result-new"]'; ` give you the results your after?

Comment: It seems like your pipe character... is not a pipe character. You have `｜` instead of `|`. I downloaded your document and I get 514 matches with your expression, after fixing it.

Comment: @Jeto, what's the difference between:｜ instead of |? And how can I one be sure it's the correct character?

Comment: @forgodsakehold Well... The correct one is the one from your keyboard :) You can use http://www.mauvecloud.net/charsets/CharCodeFinder.html or similar services (or build a simple JS script yourself) to check the ascii code behind it.